# Playing and cueing up / preloading sound in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, browser-cache, preloader

I've seen a number of questions here that ask how to play sound in JavaScript. They mostly seem to rely on creating an object with `autoplay` true. I have about 20 or 30 very small sound clips that I want to play (only one at a time), but I want to pre-load them so they're ready to go on cue. This means I can't just create a DOM `object` (or `sound`) node because the sound will start loading when I want it to actually start playing.

Should I create a load of `object` or `sound` elements in the HTML with `autoplay` `false` to ensure the sounds are loaded? I heard that, at least in Chrome, having many sound objects hammers performance. Could I bring them into browser cache some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this the other day and was pretty impressed.[SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), Javascript framework for audio.

Used to create this little bit of genius: [Wheels of Steel](http://wheelsofsteel.net/)

If someone had told me 2 years ago that you'd be able to DJ through a webpage I would have slapped the sandwich out of their smug mouth and scoffed.